# Get if object is created by using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a request that am not able to solve:

Lets suppose I have this class:

```
    public class DummyPoint {
    
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private final String id;
    
        /**
         * @param x
         * @param y
         */
        public DummyPoint(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            if(am getting created by reflection??) {
                this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            }else {
                this.id = "Reflected";
            }
        }
...
    }
```

In my project that class **DummyPoint**  can be instantiated by:

```
DummyPoint dp  = new DummyPoint(0,0);
dp.getX();
dp.getY();
dp.getId();
```

**BUT** it can be generated by reflection too:

## Question:

I would like to know if I can discriminate between an object generated by reflection or not **like am trying to do in the constructor.**

Is that possible???

## What I tried so far:

```
final DummyPoint dp0 = DummyPoint.class.getConstructor(int.class, int.class).newInstance(0, 0);
final DummyPoint dp1 = new DummyPoint(0, 0);

// ??????
System.out.println(dp0.getId());
System.out.println(dp1.getId());
```

but both objects are not showing concrete differences in order to make a choice.

thanks

Comment: short answer is not. Just try System.out.println(dp0.getClass().equals(dp1.getClass()));

Comment: What is the point of knowing that?

Comment: The reflection generated objects must be logged, but the others not.

Comment: Can't you use a third parameter in the constructor (boolean) to differentiate them? `boolean byReflection`

Comment: Java tries pretty hard to make this impossible.  This really isn't the sort of thing you should be doing.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know whether this is the best way to get it done. But you can determine it by inspecting the current call stack and checking whether it contains calls for reflection methods. One rough implementation of this will be like this. Add this method to your `DummyPoint` class

```
public boolean isUsingReflection() {
    StackTraceElement[] stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (StackTraceElement stackElement : stack) {
        String className = stackElement.getClassName();
        String methodName = stackElement.getMethodName();
        if("java.lang.reflect.Constructor".equals(className) &&
                "newInstance".equals(methodName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And modify your constructor like this

```
public DummyPoint(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    if(!isUsingReflection()) {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }else {
        this.id = "Reflected";
    }
}
```